# How to resolve this NetBeans error: "Make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running"?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, netbeans-8, jboss-eap-7

I am working on a Web Application using Maven, NetBeans 8.2 and jboss-eap 7.1 . I wrote the code below to test the Restful but when I run my code, I got this ERROR below :

`Make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running.`

This is my code:

HelloWorld.java

```
package com.myws.webservice;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/")
public class HelloWorld {


    @Inject
    HelloService helloService;

    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces({ "application/xml" })
    public String getHelloWorldXML() {
        return "<xml><result>" + helloService.createHelloMessage("World") + "</result></xml>";
    }

}
```

HelloService.java

```
package com.myws.webservice;

public class HelloService {

    String createHelloMessage(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }    
}
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation/jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs/jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Any help understanding how to proceed with this error from here? Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Although my server is running, it's give me this warning : make sure the project has been deployed successfully and the server is running.               Note that my project is working but when I add a RESTful web service, netbeans shows me the error above